# jQuery: bind another event to object

Tags: jquery, event-handling, bind

i've made a textbox widget which will highlight onFocus (and "un-highlight" onblur).
my question: i'd like to append another event to the blur-event AFTERWARDS which will eg. display a messsagebox.

i know i can assign multiple events with bind but i'd need to add that extra event after bind was already assigned.

how would this be possible?

thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to bind to this other event after blur is triggered, or right after blur is bound?

Comment: Biggest problem is that different browsers attach events in different order. so in order to do what you want you should focus on the script you bind to the onfocus instead. In the script you can set up the order of events yourself, instead of letting the browser decide for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to bind after blur has triggered:

```
$('.myelement').blur(function() {

    $(this).bind('mycustomevent', function() {
        // code here
    });

});
```

If you are wanting to bind right after blur has bound:

```
$('.myelement')
    .blur(function() {
        // code here
    })
    .bind('mycustomevent', function() {
        // code here
    });
```

If you want to trigger the SAME functionality with blur AND your custom event:

```
$('.myelement').bind('blur mycustomevent', function() {
    // code here
});
```

jQuery Binding: http://api.jquery.com/bind/